# Cucumber on IntelliJ: getting errors as soon as I set up new project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cucumber

I've been stuck for hours and I'm a bit confused, as I've tried to follow quite a few tutorials to set up Cucumber (Java version) + Selenium using IntelliJ as an IDE but I always end up getting errors from the very beginning, so I'm guessing there either is something the tutorials don't mention or some misconfiguration on my IDE.

This is something of what I've tried:

First, created a Maven project in IntelliJ IDEA and added dependencies for cucumber, junit and selenium to my pom.xml:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Then I created some structure for my project:

- a folder named "resources" within src/test.
- a folder named "features" within src/test/resources.
- a package named "step_definitions" within src/test/java.
- a file called MyTest.feature in the src/test/resources/features folder

In my MyTest.feature I added a simple test like this:

```
Feature: Check addition in Google calculator

  Scenario: Addition
    Given I open google
    When I enter "2+2" in search textbox
    Then I should get the result as "4"
```

Then from my feature file I auto-generated step definitions by using the IDE functionality (alt+enter > create step definitions), and I got a new file: MyStepDefs.java which I placed in src/test/java/step_definitions (leaving it in just src/test/java makes no difference), with the following contents:

```
package step_definitions;
import cucumber.api.PendingException;

public class MyStepdefs {
    public MyStepdefs() {
        Given("^I open google$", () -> {
            // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
            throw new PendingException();
        });}
}
```

The thing is, this is already showing errors. The "Given" keyword is not recognized: **Cannot resolve method 'Given(java.lang.String)'**

And on "new PendingException()" I get: **Incompatible types. Required: java.lang.Throwable. Found: cucumber.api.PendingException**

This sounds fishy, as it's auto-generated code so I assume it should be error-free (but it's not).

So I tried replacing this auto-generated code with something I got from [this](http://artoftesting.com/automationTesting/cucumberWithSeleniumSetup.html) tutorial but then I get a "not applicable to method" error on @Before, @After, @Given, @When, @Then keywords.

```
package step_definitions;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import cucumber.api.java.After;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

public class googleCalcStepDefinition {

    protected WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    @Given("^I open google$")
    public void I_open_google() {
        //Set implicit wait of 10 seconds and launch google
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
    }

    @When("^I enter \"([^\"]*)\" in search textbox$")
    public void I_enter_in_search_textbox(String additionTerms) {
        //Write term in google textbox
        WebElement googleTextBox = driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq"));
        googleTextBox.sendKeys(additionTerms);

        //Click on searchButton
        WebElement searchButton = driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfb"));
        searchButton.click();
    }

    @Then("^I should get result as \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void I_should_get_correct_result(String expectedResult) {
        //Get result from calculator
        WebElement calculatorTextBox = driver.findElement(By.id("cwos"));
        String result = calculatorTextBox.getText();

        //Verify that result of 2+2 is 4
        Assert.assertEquals(result, expectedResult);

        driver.close();
    }

    @After
    public void closeBrowser() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

What am I missing? Is there any way I can set up a fresh new project that uses Cucumber (Java) + Selenium on the IntelliJ IDE? Or is it just not possible at all?

Thanks!

Comment: I've opened the project from the link in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.2 and [cannot reproduce the problem](https://i.imgur.com/UtOZpuw.png). See if the [Cucumber for Java](https://i.imgur.com/ipJ9zYp.png) plug-in is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the Java JDK 9 that I had recently downloaded was the culprit. I went back to square 1 and started the project with JDK 8 and everything works as expected now.

Comment: You are right. Cucumber does not yet support Java 9.